# How should I email my graduate advisor if I did not hear anything?

Tags: graduate-school, projects

I am a graduate student at a University and I am working on academic project under my advisor's guidance. I had emailed two weeks back about my project update (which helps him grade my project hours for the semester as Satisfactory/Unsatisfactory) and the reply was  "Lets talk next week. If you don't hear from me, please call/email me". 
I  messaged again after a week to see whether its a convenient time to give  a call, but I did not get any reply.

I waited for quite a time and its been two weeks now. I was also working on couple of other projects and was quite hesitant to message again.  I also thought it is vacation as the semester ended. Now, I am unsure how to write an email.

However, I was given a Satisfactory without any discussion or checking my project, which is still good, as I really made some progress on the project.

Can anyone help me by giving a suggestion on how to handle this situation?

Edit: I have also taken one of my advisor's courses and he is pretty cool. I have never seen him getting angry for anything. Its just that I am confused and blaming my hesitant nature now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like he is stressed and a bit disorganized.  Take pity on him and write again.  "How's it going, do you have some time to meet this week?"  Something like that.

Comment: Ahh, that's right! I think, I am overthinking these days. :)